# How to use coordinator layout with frame layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-framelayout, coordinator-layout

I was creating a view that has a navigation drawer with a floating action button and a custom toolbar. It looks like this:
[image]
The question is: 
Should I use coordinator layout inside the frame layout like this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    android:title="@string/app_name"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Or frame layout inside coordinator layout like this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:title="@string/app_name"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

They both seem to work fine but I wanted to know that which one is better and why?

Comment: You don't need the `<FrameLayout>`. It's not a requirement of `DrawerLayout`. The main content can be any `View` or `ViewGroup`, so the `<FrameLayout>` would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike M. for his comment. Turned out the Frame Layout is not required with Drawer Layout. The layout will work without the Frame Layout.

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:title="@string/app_name"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```